# Problem with conformal display

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

Conformably and unambiguously map the area $D$ onto the area $D_1$
$$D_1=\left \{ w:\mathrm{Im}w>0 \right \}$$[image]

I have not been able to solve this problem...

I just figured out that from $x>1$ you can make $y>0$, and from this you can make a unit circle, with $0$ being converted to a particular $z$, and from this circle you can theoretically make whatever you want, but still it does not work

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you have "figured out"? Also, I assume D is a subset of the upper half-plane, correct?

Comment: Here's what I realised:

If $x>1$, then $y>0$, hence we get a unit circle. At the point $0$ a particular $z$ turns. Theoretically from this circle you can make what you need by the condition, but it does not work

Comment: Do you know the formula for conformal mapping when the region is bounded by a "polygon" made up of arcs of circles?  Apply that here.